# Springboot @Async in multiserver environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-boot-admin

We have a requirement to write to the Database in @async mode. We have two servers and one DB. Its working fine on local environment but on the server, the request is going to both the servers and for single request, its inserting same records in DB two times.

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score -1):

two servers got the one request? you do not use nginx for loadbalance?

Comment: multi server envrioment it is recommend to use distributed lock

Comment: single request is going to both the server, ideally it should not go. We are using netflix/ribbon as load balancer. Need to understand that, @async is culprit of sending same request to two different servers?